# Differential Geometry Previous Qualifying Exam Question wedge of differential of two forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a compact, connected, and orientable smooth manifold of dimension 6. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be 2-forms on $M$. Show that there is a point of $M$ where $d\alpha \wedge d\beta = 0$. Hint: integrate

I am stuck on how to approach this function. It seems like Stokes' Theorem would be the best approach, but we know nothing about the boundary of the manifold. In addition, if $d\alpha \wedge d\beta$ turns out to be an orientation form, we would have that there is no such point in $M$, so how do we know that this doesn't happen? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps when they say "let $M$ be a ... manifold", rather than "manifold with boundary" it is already implicitly assumed that $\partial M = \emptyset$. Also, $d \alpha \wedge d\beta = d(\alpha \wedge d\beta)$ since $d^2 = 0$. So, the form $6$-form you're given is in fact exact; however volume forms on compact orientable manifolds cannot be exact.

Comment: Thank you for the help! We figured that it was the case that $\partial M = \emptyset$ since then when we apply Stoke's theorem, we do at least get that
$$\int_M d\alpha \wedge d\beta = 0,$$
but that was as far as we got before we started to spin in circles. We didn't think of using the fact that the form was exact, though! Can you possibly explain a little more on why volume forms on compact orientable manifolds can't be exact?

Comment: There are a few questions on this site explaining it in more detail, but the idea is that since the form is exact and $\partial M = \emptyset$, integrating it over $M$ equals $0$ by Stokes' theorem. However, if it is also a volume form, then integrating the volume form on the manifold gives the volume of the manifold, which is strictly non-zero. Hence, this is a contradiction

Comment: And how does it follow from the integral being zero that there is eventually a point in $M$ over which the form is zero?

Comment: @Berci: Choose a fixed volume form $\eta$ and write your exact $6$-form as $f\eta$. If $f$ never changes sign, how can the integral $\int_M f\eta$ be $0$?

Comment: Excellent! That answers my question. Thank you all so much!